# React FullCalendar.IO: Drag events outside calendar and drop to external container

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am building a simple event manager application using React and FullCalendar.io. My requirement is that the events should be draggable between the calendar and an external container. The external container lives on a different component.

I was able to drag events from external container to calendar using the ThirdPartyDraggable class from "@fullcalendar/interaction" but I am trying to drag the events from calendar to external container. I am not able to find a solution for this. Any pointers to achieve this is much appreciated.

I'm attaching a simple image of what I am trying to do. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: In terms of integration with fullcalendar, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/third-party-dragging is probably the place to start reading

Comment: try this [link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDragStop)

Comment: @Sahul that only applies to events dragged _within_ the calendar, which isn't what is being asked about here